# How to use Foundation 4 Button control to asp.net server control Button?

Tags: asp.net, zurb-foundation

I want to apply CssClass "nice blue radius button" to asp.net button, however it looks not working as the screenshot saying:

[screenshot http://img46.imageshack.us/img46/4859/trz.png](http://img46.imageshack.us/img46/4859/trz.png)

Is there anyway to apply the Foundation 4 button to asp.net button?

Comment: is the .css file included in <head>, if yes tell me the href="" part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to apply `class="button nice radius green bottom"`

```
<input type="submit" class="button nice radius green bottom" />
```